# Android Video Player

Tags: android

My video player not working in HTC Eris

```
    Intent tostart = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
         tostart.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(photos_videos_uri_list.get(position)),
           "video/*");
         v.getContext().startActivity(tostart);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Please use a real MIME type. `video/*` is not a real MIME type.
2. There is no guarantee that any given device will have something that will respond to `ACTION_VIEW` on any particular real MIME type.

You can use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to see if there is something on the device that will respond to your `Intent`. Then, if there is no match, you can always play the video yourself using `VideoView`.

Answer (score -1):

First, I am so sorry to hear that your video player not working in HTC Eris. Second, as we all know, the operation system of this smart phone is android. Would you mind install F2FSoft Blu ray Ripper to change your video format? The reason that why your video can not be played in your phone is resulted from unmatched.